# JSON Parse Error: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a database, analysis.php and index.php webpages. The analysis.php gets the data from the database, sorts it in a required pattern, and then echoes the `json_encode($array);` into a `div` with the id 'data'. I am trying to get that JSON Data and parse it in the index.php page.

However I am getting an error. `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

I am trying to get this data everytime the user selects an option from a select box.

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.select' , function () {
    var identification = $(this).val();
    var JSONText = $(this).closest('div[id|="module"]').find('p[id="JSON"]');
    JSONText.load('analysis.php?data=' + identification + ' #data');
    console.log("JSON Imported: '" + identification + "'");
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSONText.text());
    console.log(JSONText.text());
});
```

**EDIT:** As you can see I have the snippet `console.log(JSON.text());`. The output of the JSON that I get is correct. The only issue I think might be is that the quotes are all `"` instead of the JSON quotes being different from the outer quotes.

Comment: how does your json look ? Also do not name your variable `JSON` as the browsers native json parser is assigned to it. Just seeing this, wtf are you doing there ? Use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: Check the console for the XHR of `analysis.php`. The JSON response might be incomplete to begin with.

Comment: The JSON Response seems valid. I have checked its validity on http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Also LJ_1102. Does getJSON give you the ability to get a specific part of the webpage? Filtering it by the div ID?

Comment: @shadoweye14 No it does not, have a look at the link. jQuery.load is async, you're trying to parse the JSON before its actually loaded. Using `jQuery.getJSON` loades the content, does the parsing and provides a callback you can bind to.

Comment: @MVP I am appending this hashtag to just get the text from a specific part of the webpage. Not the whole webpage. In this case, just a div with an id `data`. @LJ_1102 Sorry I am still new to jQuery, but have't I allready loaded the JSON on line 4. I am loading it to a `<p>` element and then reading from it to parse it.

Comment: LJ_1102 already answered correctly. You need to wait for the callback of your AJAX  request (`.load`) before accessing the content of your `<p>` element.

Comment: @shadoweye14 when calling `jQuery.load` you start downloading the JSON from your server, but the other code is executed right after that, so before the download is complete hence "asynchronous". So you need to use the complete callback to be sure your data is actually loaded.

Comment: I didnt downvote. Also keep the last part of my answer in mind when using MVPs solution.

Comment: The callback? Will do. Thanks

Comment: No, the "*load as html, insert into dom, retrieve using `text` is dangerous*". I've added an example to clarify the correct usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[jQuery.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous, you're trying to parse the JSON before its actually loaded. Using [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) loads the content, does the parsing and provides a callback you can bind to.

**jQuery.load loads the content as HTML and sets the innerHTML of the selected element, you could bind the `complete` handler here aswell, but you may encounter issues by loading the content as HTML and then using `text` to retrieve it from the DOM as some parts of your JSON may be interpreted as HTML elements.**

Better use this:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.select' , function () {
    var identification = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(
        'analysis.php?data=' + identification + ' #data',
        function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I tried that code, however it produces no results. The `console.log(data);` does not fire at all. There is no indication that the getJSON function does anything.

Comment: Are you actually loading plain JSON ? Or does the output of `analysis.php` contain non json output ? If so, you could replace `getJSON` with `load` and use `console.log($.parseJSON(data))` but it would be better(cleaner) to have `analysis.php` output plain JSON maybe introduce another parameter like `ajax=true`.

Comment: The page does contain HTML Elements as defined in my question above. I want to grab the text from a div with a specific ID.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to LJ_1102's solution, here is a way to fix your current snippet:

```
JSONText.load('analysis.php?data=' + identification + ' #data', function() {

    console.log("JSON Imported: '" + identification + "'");
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSONText.text());
    console.log(JSONText.text());

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) Appreciate it.

Comment: This is quite error prone, as soon as the json contains any html characters it'll not be correctly retrieved using jquerys `text` method. Also it opens all gates for [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.